# Full Background layer with transparent box in the center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I am creating an app that only crop picture based on what is viewed in box overlay in the center. Is there any ways to make it outside the box black, leaving only the center box transparent. I have tried using margin in glsurfaceView, the result is what I need, but it only make the preview smaller.

[This is what I need](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8rpl1oba2zqw3f/Screenshot_2015-07-08-12-02-35.png?dl=0)

[And this is what I am doing right now.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1y2uk8115lsbt7/Screenshot_2015-07-08-12-03-48.png?dl=0)

These are the two similar images. If you compare these two images, giving margin to surfaceView only make the preview smaller.

This is the code for surfaceView.

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code for overlay box

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchFilter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Filter"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/overlay_bg_green"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takePhoto"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Take Photo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you're trying to crop the image from the Camera preview? Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655236/how-to-set-background-to-the-outer-portion-of-frame-in-android-using-surfaceview/ ?

Comment: yes, more or less similar like that. But I can crop the image, the problem now is to create a preview like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8rpl1oba2zqw3f/Screenshot_2015-07-08-12-02-35.png?dl=0

Comment: Perhaps a FrameLayout? Grafika uses a custom version (AspectFrameLayout) to adjust the SurfaceView size to conform to the video's aspect ratio in the "play video (SurfaceView)" activity. See https://github.com/google/grafika , esp. PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java .